# How to optimise this regex to match string (1234-12345-1)

Tags: regex, validation, number-formatting

I've got this RegEx example: http://regexr.com?34hihsvn

I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way of writing it, or perhaps a more optimised way?

Here are the rules:

- Digits and dashes only.
- Must not contain more than 10 digits.
- Must have two hyphens.
- Must have at least one digit between each hyphen.
- Last number must only be one digit.

I'm new to this so would appreciate any hints or tips.

In case the link expires, the text to search is

```
----------
22-22-1
22-22-22
333-333-1
333-4444-1
4444-4444-1
4444-55555-1
55555-4444-1
666666-7777777-1
88888888-88888888-1
1-1-1
88888888-88888888-22
22-333-
333-22
----------
```

My regex is: `\b((\d{1,4}-\d{1,5})|(\d{1,5}-\d{1,4}))-\d{1}\b`

I'm using this site for testing: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Thanks for any help,
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex I came up with:

```
(?=\b[\d-]{3,10}-\d\b)\b\d+-\d+-\d\b
```

This uses a look-ahead to validate the information before attempting the match. So it looks for between 3-10 characters in the class of `[\d-]` followed by a `dash` and a `digit`. And then after that you have the actual match to confirm that the format of your string is actually `digit(dash)digit(dash)digit`.

From your sample strings this regex matches:

```
22-22-1
333-333-1
333-4444-1
4444-4444-1
4444-55555-1
55555-4444-1
1-1-1
```

It also matches the following strings:

```
22-7777777-1
1-88888888-1
```

Comment: This also matches both 22-7777777-1 and 1-88888888-1 which is also a requirement that I missed off.

Comment: Based on your description I was hoping this was a requirement. I'm glad to see I was correct. I'll update my answer with this. Hopefully this helped.

Answer (score 1):

Your regexp only allows a first and second group of digits with a maximum length of 5. Therefore, valid strings like `1-12345678-1` or `123456-1-1` won't be matched.

This regexp works for the given requirements:

```
\b(?:\d\-\d{1,8}|\d{2}\-\d{1,7}|\d{3}\-\d{1,6}|\d{4}\-\d{1,5}|\d{5}\-\d{1,4}|\d{6}\-\d{1,3}|\d{7}\-\d{1,2}|\d{8}\-\d)\-\d\b
```

([RegExr](http://regexr.com?34hjr))

Comment: Good point! I overlooked that I needed it to match 22-7777777-1 or 1-88888888-1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this with the `m` modifier *(switch the multiline mode on)*:

```
^\d(?!.{12})\d*-\d+-\d$
```

or this one without the `m` modifier:

```
\b\d(?!.{12})\d*-\d+-\d\b
```

By design these two patterns match at least three digits separated by hyphens *(so no need to put a `{5,n}` quantifier somewhere, it's useless)*.
Patterns are also build to fail faster:

- I have chosen to start them with a digit `\d`, this way each beginning of a line or word-boundary not followed by a digit is immediately discarded. Other thing, using only one digit, I know the remaining string length.
- Then I test the upper limit of the string length with a negative lookahead that test if there is one more character than the maximum length *(if there are 12 characters at this position, there are 13 characters at least in the string)*. No need to use more descriptive that the dot meta-character here, the goal is to quickly test the length.
- finally, I describe the end of string without doing something particular. That is probably the slower part of the pattern, but it doesn't matter since the overwhelming majority of unnecessary positions have already been discarded.

Comment: ok, so this works as well... What is multi-line mode? How does this Regex work? Cheers.

Comment: Ok, I have add an explanation